# 403 fatal error when pushing from command line to github

Tags: github, command-line

When working in the command line and attempting to push a Git project to GitHub, after entering my credentials, I get a fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/TDavis14/git_practice.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403. How do I remedy this?

I have cleared the website cache, cookies, etc. and have regenerated my access token for GitHub, but the result is still the same.

Comment: You probably entered your password in your password field. but instead, you need to put a [personal access token](https://github.com/settings/tokens) with repo and user permissions

Comment: I originally had entered my password, and then realized I had done it wrong, so I went into GitHub and generated a fine grain personal access token. It still is not working.